What is meant by "Halloween is one of the biggest holidays for candy sales?" (Halloween is not a federal holiday in the US)
I read this in Britannica.com

The custom of trick-or-treating, in which children dress up in costume and solicit treats from neighbors, became popular in the United States in the early 20th century as Irish and Scottish communities revived the Old World custom of “guising,” in which a person would dress in costume and tell a joke, recite a poem, or perform some other trick in exchange for a piece of fruit or other treat.
By 1950, trick-or-treating for candy had become one of Halloween’s most popular activities.
Today, Halloween is one of the biggest holidays for candy sales in the United States, estimated to be more than $3 billion, according to the National Retail Federation.

What is meant by "biggest holidays for candy sales"?
Does it mean that people normally buy candy when there are holidays?
Edit-1.
Reference Cambridge dictionary:

holiday | English meaning -
a time when someone does not go to work or school but is free to do what they want, such as travel or relax.

Both Halloween and Valentine's are not official federal holidays in the United States.
So why is "holidays" used to describe candy sales during Halloween?
"one of the biggest holidays for candy sales".
https://www.britannica.com/story/why-do-we-celebrate-halloween#:~:text=Halloween%27s%20origins%20can%20be%20traced,bonfires%20to%20ward%20off%20spirits

Is your question about the construction one of the superlative Xs for something or about the cultural association of holidays and candy?

@TimR It is about the meaning of the phrase "one of the biggest holidays for candy sales".

Are you wondering about the connection of candy and  Halloween because you're ignorant about that holiday, or are you trying to parse the phrase biggest holidays for?

This federal holiday distinction you've made in an edit is laughable.  "Logical"? It is the biggest for candy sales, just as the small chain of islands in my answer is the "biggest for ... scuba diving and snorkeling".  The prepositional phrase supplies the metric for the suplerlative.

@TimR Sorry I didn't notice your answer because there was no notification. Do you agree with #JamesK answer - Holiday" in this context doesn't mean "Federal Holiday", it just means any day that the population considers to be "special".

The definitions for holiday in Merriam-Webster don't fit Halloween: "holy day" and "a day on which one is exempt from work". Cambridge is similar. But Wikipedia includes "minor secular observances" like Monkey Day (December 14), International Talk Like a Pirate Day and April Fools' Day, and the Britannica author obviously counts Halloween. But asking whether something counts as a holiday isn't particularly on-topic.

It's always better to look to encyclopedias or other reference books rather than dictionaries for a nuanced analysis of a topic such as "what is a holiday".

@StuartF Could you explain if someone can get information in encyclopaedia what is the purpose of the site? This definition of holiday isn't known to most of the learners.

Yes, in America (and many other cultures) buying and sharing sweet food is a common part of many festivals.  At Easter, we gift and eat chocolate eggs.  At Christmas, gingerbread and candy canes are some of many sweet treats.  On Valentine's Day, a box of chocolates might be an appropriate gift for a girlfriend. "Candy" or "candies" in this context includes chocolates, toffee, and other "sweet treats", not just boiled sugar candy.
But Halloween is celebrated by "Trick or treat", in which children dress up (as ghosts, witches, monsters etc.) and visit neighbours' houses to collect candy. Adults buy candy to give to children.  So candy sales are "big" at Halloween.  It is one of the biggest festivals for candy sales.
"Holiday" in this context doesn't mean "Federal Holiday", it just means any day that the population considers to be "special".  Many of the most important holidays in the USA are not "Federal Holidays".  That includes Easter (and Good Friday), Mardi Gras (Shrove Tuesday), Flag Day (June 14th) and Valentine's Day (Feb 14th). When a text talks about "holidays (in the USA)" it would normally include these commonly celebrated religious and cultural observations. See https://www.usa.gov/holidays

I thought candy meaning is only
candy
plural candies
: crystallized sugar formed by boiling down sugar syrup.
But in this report, they included chocolates too.
"Halloween may have trick-or-treating and Valentine's Day may be synonymous with boxes of chocolates, but Easter last year, Americans bought $823 million in creme-filled eggs, chocolate rabbits and colored marshmallow Peeps, according to Nielsen data. That narrowly beats out Halloween as the most lucrative week of the year for candy retailers."
https://www.cnbc.com/2016/03/24/easter-wins-the-candy-battle.html

I think the OP's question was about how the phrase worked, not the customs. Though the above comment suggests there's some uncertainty around the practicalities too. @JamesMathai beware of using dictionary entries that are too narrow, as well as too broad. While "hardened sugar syrup" is one very specific definition, if you look a bit more I'm sure you'll find some broader ones, like Cambridge's "a sweet food made from sugar or chocolate."

@JamesMathai Your question was not clear: Candy in American English is Sweets in British English.

@Lambie I asked about the phrase and its meaning - Does it mean that people normally buy candies when holidays are there ? There may be many holidays when people don't buy candy. The comment is just for clarification, otherwise I think this answer is appropriate.

I'm sure there are some American public holidays not associated with the buying of sweets/candy, but of those that are, Hallowe'en is the most important for sales.

@JamesMathai I thought you'd go for the comparison with Diwali. I guess I was mistaken about that.///Hallow'een is not really a festival.

@JamesMathai - the Americans use the word 'candy' for what we call 'sweets' or 'confectionery'.

@JamesMathai Please don't clarify your question using comments, especially comments on an answer. Instead, please use the "edit" button under the question itself to make sure the question is clear on its own.


"My primary concern lies with the usage of the word 'holiday' in the phrase 'one of the biggest holidays for candy sales'."  I have edited my question to "Is it logical to say that "Halloween is one of the biggest holidays for candy sales " ; as it is not a federal holiday. You cannot include Valentine's day too.


"Holiday" in this context is inclusive of religious and cultural observances. Easter, Flag Day and Valentine's are all holidays in this context.  I've edited.

The word Halloween (also spelled Hallowe'en) is derived from All Hallows' Eve, the eve of All Hallows' Day, more commonly known today as All Saints' Day. Hallow is derived from the Old English term hālig meaning holy.
In some countries, but not in the US or the UK,  November 1st is indeed a public holiday. It is a religious day (a holy day) when Christians woship the saints of the Church both well-known and unknown. It is said that the Catholic Church alone honours over 10,000 saints. Schools are closed and many workplaces will close on that day too. In some countries this holiday also extends to November 2nd,  "All Souls Day", a day when families dedicate time remembering the deaths of friends and loved ones and praying for their souls to enter Heaven.
It's important to note that although All Saints Day and All Souls Day are recorded on the Christian calendar; its religious significance, especially in Western Christianity, has seen a steady continuous decline since the mid-20th century. Fewer Christians today actually attend Mass, pray, or visit cemeteries or memorials on these days. And today Halloween is for all intents and purposes a secular celebration rather than a religious holiday.
Courtesy of Wikipedia, this is a list of countries and states where November 1st is a Public Holiday:

Andorra, Austria, Belgium, Benin, Burkina Faso, Burundi, Cape Verde, Central African Republic, Chad, Chile, Colombia, Congo, Croatia, East Timor, France, French Guiana, French Polynesia, Gabon, Guadeloupe, Guatemala, Hungary, Italy, Ivory Coast, Lebanon, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Madagascar, Martinique, Mauritius, Peru, Poland, Portugal, Saint Barthélemy, Saint Martin, Saint Pierre and Miquelon, San Marino, Senegal, Seychelles, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Togo, the Vatican and Venezuela.

Even though 31st October and 1st November are not Public Holidays in the USA or in the UK; Halloween is celebrated—a lot—in these two countries, especially so in the US, and especially by children. The sales of candy, sweets (not desserts!), chocolate bars, treats etc. go through the roof (increase) during the weeks leading up to the much-awaited fun event which is usually celebrated in the evening until night, which means schools and workplaces do not have to be closed!

Do you agree with this explanation - "Holiday" in this context doesn't mean "Federal Holiday", it just means any day that the population considers to be "special".

Generally, today in Western society, a "holiday" is similar to a celebration, like weddings, birthdays and any other occasion that is out of the ordinary. Halloween may not be considered a "holy day" per se, but it is celebrated, and is  also catching on in Italy, as I'd imagine in other central Europen countries such as France and Spain. In the UK, 5th November (Guy Fawkes Day) was the one for kids, you still had to go to school and work  though.

@JamesMathai Christmas Eve is not a public holiday but many schools close on that day as well as Christmas Day and St. Stephen's (AKA Boxing Day). In many countries festivities begin on 24th December and continue until January 6th. The holiday season refers to the "period". Likewise with  Halloween, I think  the Spanish-speaking countries in South America  and Mexicans   continued their traditions when they immigrated to the US. Anyway, the idea of a holiday can extend beyond a day or two of public holidays, and any break from school and work is often called a holiday.

The same idea applied to India might go like this:

Diwali is one of the biggest holidays for candle sales.

And to Brazil:

Carnaval is one of the biggest holidays for confetti sales.

And to France:

Christmas and New Year's are two of the biggest holidays for champagne sales.

People may buy some product to celebrate a  holiday tradition.
That then can be the biggest [most important] holiday [for the purchase of] candy, candles, champagne, or whatever item the holiday uses.
In other words, the holiday on which the most sales occur.
candy in American English is sweets in British English.

It's not totally clear to me exactly what the OP's confusion was, but my guess it might be about how, in "biggest X for Y sales," although functionally "biggest" appears to modify "x," it's really the "Y sales" that are big. Might be worth explicating that a bit.

big is a word with a lot of slop.  It is used to describe things that are not physically big and it is  also used rather  elliptically to describe things indirectly.
Consider this rough analog to the sentence in your question:

This  chain of small islands is one of the biggest destinations for scuba diving and snorkeling.

Lurking behind that utterance is the author's (reasonable) belief that the reader will know that scuba diving and snorkeling are among the things tourists seek out when they visit a  place in the middle of an ocean.  The author assumes that the reader understands that "destinations" is being used to mean "places that tourists visit", not merely a place where one arrives.  The author  further assumes that the reader knows that tourism is central to the economy of many places.  And so in the utterance above, what is being described is the large amount of revenue from tourism generated by scuba diving and snorkeling for that chain of small islands.

Today, Halloween is one of the biggest holidays for candy sales in the United States, estimated to be more than $3 billion, according to the National Retail Federation.

In the US, "candy sales" includes a wide range of chocolaty and sugary sweets, including brands that are known in other parts of the world, like Snickers, Mars, and Hershey's.  It is indeed a multi-billion-dollar industry. In fact, when an international software company rolled out its supply chain management software implementation twenty-some years ago for a major candy manufacturer, and there were serious bugs in the integration with some of the candy maker's existing software, the maker failed to meet orders for $100 million in product during the Halloween season.


"My primary concern lies with the usage of the word 'holidays' in the phrase 'one of the biggest holidays for candy sales'."


@JamesMathai  What about that phrase is giving you trouble?  You seem unable to move the discussion in any meaningful direction.  So I will have to assume you were lazy and didn't bother to look up Halloween and how it is celebrated.

"Big" has several definitions and is not always related to physical size. Cambridge notes that it can mean important, having a great deal of influence, popular, or simply used for emphasis.
In your example it indirectly refers to the metric by which it is being measured - candy sales. Candy sales are "big" (voluminous, inflated, higher than usual etc) at Halloween, therefore Halloween, when measured by those sales is also "big".

"My primary concern lies with the usage of the word 'holidays" in the phrase 'one of the biggest holidays for candy sales'."
